# How to avoid this restful service request error?

Tags: java, rest, url

I have spring web project that provides a restful service through URL, which I hosted on my local machine for testing.

```
http://localhost:8090/classify?classificationInput={"inputInfo":{"inputText":"how much money","sku":"2"}}
```

Then I have a restful client to send request to the serve above and get result back as a Json string. The problem is that if I use multi threads to send many requests to the restful service, I will get a portion of request processing failure, as shown below. This is because my Web application is sending requests to another restful service to process the data, and because it takes some time to process each request, it failed on some request and issue the following exception, a typical exception:

```
ERROR com.nlu.qe.service.executors.Parser [107] [executeParser] - Parser 
IOException failed! 1887628
```

how is that happen

```
http://XX.XX.69.251/LexicalAnalyze?Type=graphjson&Key=Lsdif238fj&action=headdown&Sentence= message
```

The code gives this exception looks like the following:

```
private String executeParser(String sku, String inputText, String msgId) {

    String jsonOutput = null;
    String urlStr = "http://XX.XX.69.251/LexicalAnalyze?Type=graphjson&Key=Lsdif238fj&action=headdown&Sentence=";
    try {
        String encodedInputText = URLEncoder.encode("\"" + inputText + "\"", "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(urlStr + encodedInputText);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        jsonOutput = in.readLine();
        in.close();
        LOGGER.info("{} is parsed by {} {} {}", sku, urlStr, msgId, inputText);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parser UnsupportedEncodingException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parser MalformedURLException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parser IOException failed! {} {} {} {}", sku, inputText, urlStr, msgId);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonOutput;
}
```

My guess is that when large quantities of requests due to multi-thread are sent to restful service, the service (shown in code above) is too busy to handle all of them, so some requests failed. In particular, this part failed:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Is this the real cause and if yes, how to avoid that? I want to use multiple threads to speed up the process.

EDIT:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://xx.xx.69.251/LexicalAnalyze?Type=graphjson&Key=Lsdif238fj&action=headdown&Sentence=%22%23E-s16%E4%BB%8A%E5%A4%A9%E5%87%86%E5%A4%87%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%95%E5%B1%85%E7%84%B6%E6%B6%A8%E4%BB%B7%E4%BA%86%22
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.executors.DParser.executeParser(DParser.java:96)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.executors.DParser.parse(DParser.java:72)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.executors.DParser$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a7e8b65c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.ump.annotation.JAnnotation.execJAnnotation(JAnnotation.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.executors.DParser$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2749ab39.parse(<generated>)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.ClassificationService.classifyQuestion(ClassificationService.java:24)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.JnluQEServiceImpl.getClassification(JnluQEServiceImpl.java:95)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.JnluQEServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$71039dbb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.nlu.qe.service.JnluQEServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1da74b6.getClassification(<generated>)
    at com.nlu.qe.controller.QueryEngineController.classify(QueryEngineController.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor56.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What's the message for the IOException, in the stack trace?
PS: this might be unrelated to the issue, but it's not recommended to call URL.openStream() directly as the connection created will have an infinite timeout. It's better to call URL.openConnection() then connection.setConnectTimeout(x) and connection.setReadTimeout(y), that way your threads won't hang forever and report a timeout occurred.

Comment: What do you mean by "what's the message for the IOException"? I printed out some informational message in the catch block, as you can see.

Comment: I am wondering why the openStream methods throws the IOException. Do you think is it because the server is busy due to multiple http requests sent it then throws the IOException?

Comment: The message in the post above is only showing what the LOGGER is printing out; if you're not seeing the output of the standard output, then would you be able to add the exception to the LOGGER is printing? Either by passing the exception directly, or by passing e.getMessage()?

Comment: @cleberz Please see the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the 502 error indicated by the error logs points out theres an error happening on the server side, not the client side. The 502 code usually means Bad Gateway, so it's either something wrong with the server itself, or with some gateway/proxy in between your client and the server redirecting the requests (depending on how the first server is calling the second server, maybe the timeouts on the second server end up being reported as 502's by the first server). I would check for the server logs of both to see whether the server is running out of connections of request handlers.